# What is the quickest way to repeat the same string followed by consecutive integers?

Tags: r, seq, rep

I want to make a column that repeats a word followed by a consecutive interger like this:

```r
rep1
rep2
rep3
rep4
rep5
…
rep200
```

Can this be done with a `seq()` command or something similar? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `paste` with `:`

```
paste0("rep", 1:200)
```

Or with `sprintf`

```
sprintf("rep%d", 1:200)
```